# how to create a dropdown list with checkbox in user control page(ascx) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to add Drop Down List with checkbox, multiple selection from drop down in asp.net c#.

I want to select multiple items from drop down control inside the user control page

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  What specifically do you mean by "Drop Down List with checkbox"?  By default a drop down list in HTML can't be customized and is rendered by the host system.  You'd need something more complex in JavaScript to mimic a drop down list, such as the Select2 plugin or the Chosen plugin.

Comment: how to add multi select dropdown in ascx page

Comment: If all you want is multi-select then the answer posted below covers that.  The control is called a `ListBox`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by making selection mode to multiple:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
            </asp:ListBox>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

for Reference see the following link 
[here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2128756.aspx?How%20to%20achieve%20multi%20select%20dropdown%20checkbox%20list%20in%20ASP%20Net)